# construct weighted shift operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable complex Hilbert space with orthonormal basis.

Let $W \in B(H)$ be a unilateral forward weighted shift. i.e. $We_n=w_n e_{n+1}$, where $(w_n) \in \ell^{\infty}$.

Show that there exists a unitary operator $U\in B(H)$ so that $U^*WU$ is a unilateral weighted shift with weight sequence $(|w_n|)_n$.

My work:

I have $    Ue_n= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{w_n}{|w_n|}e_n,& \text{if } w_n \ne 0\\
    e_n,              & \text{if } w_n=0
\end{cases} $

I showed that $U$ is unitary.

Now I want to show that $U^*WU$ is a unilateral weighted shift with weight sequence $(|w_n|)_n$.

So in the case $w_n \ne 0$, I have

$U^*WU e_n= U^*W(\frac{w_n}{|w_n|}e_n) = \frac{w_n}{|w_n|}U^*W(e_n)= \frac{w_n}{|w_n|}U^*w_n(e_{n+1}) = \frac{w_n}{|w_n|}w_nU^*(e_{n+1}) = \frac{w_n}{|w_n|}w_n\frac{w_{n+1}}{|w_{n+1}|}e_{n+1} = |w_n|e_{n+1}$.

I'm not sure if the last equality is correct, because I just sort of forced it in the last step...

If not, could someone let me know how to fix it?

Also, any other suggestions will be highly appreciated too!

Thank you.

Comment: $U$ is not unitary because it's singular. It projects $e_n$ to zero when $w_n = 0$. It would be unitary if it projected such $e_n$ to itself.

Comment: Yes! You're right. Sorry I made a typo earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a sequence $u$ such that:
$$
u_0 = 0\\
u_{n+1}=u_n+\arg w_n
$$
And for the operator $U$ holds: $Ue_n = e^{iu_n}e_n$

Now let's proove that it works:$$
U^*WUe_n = e^{iu_n}U^*We_n=e^{iu_n}w_nU^*e_{n+1}=e^{iu_n}w_ne^{-iu_{n+1}}e_{n+1}= \\=\exp(iu_n+ln|w_n|+i\arg w_n-iu_{n+1})e_{n+1}=|w_n|\exp(iun+i\arg w_n - iu_n-i\arg w_n)e_{n+1}=|w_n|e_{n+1}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response! So does it mean that the one I defined does not work?

Comment: Your attempt doesn't work. Let $w_0=i$, $w_1=1$. Then $\frac{w_0}{|w_0|}w_0\frac{w_1}{|w_1|}e_1=-e_1$ but $|w_0|e_1=e_1$

Comment: Ho did you get $U^*e_n = e^{iu_n}$? I have $U^*e_n =e^{-iu_n} $, since $\langle U^*e_n, e_m \rangle =\langle e_n, Ue_m \rangle = \langle e_n, e^{-iu_m} e_m \rangle = e^{-iu_m} \langle e_n, e_m \rangle $... which changes everything above...

Comment: You're right, I forgot that adjunction has this effect. I corrected my sollution accordingly.

Comment: It scales each vector of the basis by a constant. Note that $e^{iu_n}$ is a constant and doesn't depend on the vector which is being transformed by the operator.